# How do I securely pass data from my iOS app to my server?

Tags: ios, http, ssl

Is there a good tutorial out there for this? I want to make sure I do it properly.

Say I want to send a password a user entered in the app to my server securely. What is the protocol for this? Do I need SSL on my server? Do I need to encrypt it before sending?

How do I handle this so user information is properly managed?

Comment: Use SSL on the server. Connect using https. Done.

Comment: For a more complete answer than what rmaddy already offered I think you need to provide more detail. What information are you trying to protect and what are you protecting it from? Https connections will do a great deal to prevent third parties from readying requests in flight but that's not the only possible threat and any solution is valid only relative to the threat you're trying to protect against.

Comment: I should have been more clear. My first comment is to get the data from your app to the web server safely. That's it.

Comment: For an introduction, see https://github.com/rnapier/practical-security/blob/master/Practical%20Security.pdf. (If you happen to be in Seattle, I'll be giving an updated version of this talk at CocoaConf in a couple of weeks.) But rmaddy is exactly right: the number one biggest thing you should do is turn on HTTPS. But the second thing you should do is avoid sending passwords to the server if you can possibly avoid it. The talk discusses better solutions.

Comment: @RobNapier What about all this SSL Pinning stuff I hear so much about (and thank you for the link, I wish I could be in Seattle but it's a bit of a flight from over here!)

Comment: Pinning is very useful and recommended. The linked talk covers that with code samples in ObjC (I'll have Swift samples up after my CocoaConf talk; I just haven't pushed them yet).

Comment: @RobNapier But to be clear, if I'm communicating with a third party API pinning isn't possible unless I'm coordinating it with them explicitly, right? (Admittedly different than the case I outlined in the above post.)

Comment: If communicating directly, correct. There are good security and practical reasons for proxying the communication through your own servers, which would allow pinning. But this is a fairly rare practice.

Comment: If you know who the 3rd party is you should be able pin to them, you just need to know about their certificate which is returned with the the request. You can pin parts of the certificate such as verifying the certificate authority and domain.